# Create NodeJS query to Mongodb case insensitive and from array of data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a node.js script to query on MongoDB database from an array of data, e.g. emails. The emails data are stored as a single string, not an array. I'll also need case insensitive match from an array of input emails.

My current request is below. Please suggest if there are better ways:

```
db.users.find({email:{$in:[/Abc@gmail.com/i,/abC@hotmail.com/i]}}
```

Input array would contain the following, readin from another file:

```
var matchOn = ["Abc@gmail.com", "abC@hotmail.com"];
```

So output should contain all emails(case insensitive) if either of the emails match. How do I construct this query in NodeJS, especially I am not sure about how to specify to match on each entry of the `matchOn` array in the query and add the `/i`. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forgot ' or " around your emails adresses?

Comment: I could use or OR in but each case, how do you add the case insenstive /i to the query in JavaScript? { $or: {email: matchOn[0]}, {email: matchOn[1]}}.

Comment: I was talking about your `matchOn`variable.

Comment: Updated, the string that I am trying to match with (mathOn) should each be a string. updated in the question.

Comment: Could you post a example of your DB content?

Comment: DB contains:  {_id: 1, email: abc@gmail.com}, {_id: 2, email: abc@hotmail.com}.  so with case insensitive option, the 2 matchOn queries should get both documents.

Answer (score 0):

In newer mongo version it should be possible to use [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

It has caseSensitive option and also states that

> A string of terms that MongoDB parses and uses to query the text index. MongoDB performs a logical OR search of the terms

Which seems it should work. Never tried it myself however.

Comment: I can't modify the DB, only query. Don't text need the ability to insert it into the DB?